# Как правильно настроить уникальный класс модуля, в yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

Как правильно настроить уникальный класс модуля, в yii-2?
Интересует вариант без создание в системе GII.

Это класс, который наследуется от `yii\base\Module`

Пример того как этот класс может выглядеть:

```
namespace app\modules\forum;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->params['foo'] = 'bar';
        // ... остальной инициализирующий код ...
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** Что конкретно в функции `init()` должно быть?

---

Вот еще один варинат настройки этого класса:

> Если метод init() стал слишком громоздким из-за кода, который задает
>   свойства модуля, эти свойства можно сохранить в виде конфигурации, а
>   затем загрузить в методе init() следующим образом:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    // инициализация модуля с помощью конфигурации, загруженной из config.php
    \Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));
}
```

> При этом в конфигурационном файле config.php может быть код следующего
>   вида, аналогичный конфигурации приложения:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        // список конфигураций компонентов
    ],
    'params' => [
        // список параметров
    ],
**];
```

**Вопрос:** Что именно тут должно быть - `components` и `params`?

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут , могут быть, но не должны быть, подобные настройки, которые мы делали в `config/web.php`

Лично я, сюда еще дописал

```
return [
    'components' => [
        // список конфигураций компонентов
        // переопределяем layout по умолчанию. (Теперь при вызове модуля, будет вызываться другой шаблон, который размещён именно в самом модуле.
        'layout' => 'main.php',
    ],
    'params' => [
        // список параметров
    ],
];
```

И указываем путь к конфигурационнуму файлу самого модуля (его тоже, лучше создать в самом модуле, в папке config, на уровне уникального класса модуля):

```
Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));
```